# create a timer using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, timer, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm going to building a count down timer in my website.
my end time comes from server (it's a number like this: 10500 (which means it's 10500 minutes till the timer finish))

i can't do this, is there anybody who can help me?

```js
const [times, setTimes] = useState({ days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
const [timeToReserve, setTimeToReserve] = useState(props.reserveData.ToReserve);

React.useEffect(() => {
    timeToReserve > 0 && setTimeout(() => checkTime(), 1000);
}, [timeToReserve]);

const checkTime = () => {
    let minutesToReserve = timeToReserve - 1
    setTimeToReserve(minutesToReserve)

    let days = Math.floor(minutesToReserve / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((minutesToReserve % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((minutesToReserve % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((minutesToReserve % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    setTimes({ days, hours, minutes, seconds })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const CountDown = ({ reserveData }) => {
    const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(reserveData.ToReserve * 60);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const countDownTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            // Stop in case the time is over
            if (secondsLeft > 0) {
                return setSecondsLeft(seconds => seconds - 1);
            }
            clearTimeout(countDownTimeout);
        }, 1000);
        
        // Clean up if unmounted
        return () => clearTimeout(countDownTimeout);
    }, [secondsLeft]);
    
    const days = Math.floor(secondsLeft / (60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((secondsLeft % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((secondsLeft % (60 * 60)) / 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(secondsLeft % 60);
    return (
        <p>
            {days} days, {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
        </p>
    );
};

export default CountDown;
```

You could use this component like:

```js
<CountDown
    reserveData={{ToReserve: 24 * 6 * 60}}
/>
```